# Slow loading of the application after clicking from the AppWidget

Tags: android, android-widget

The **Floating App Widget** turns on when you click a button in the app.

I wrote a function that when clicked on Widget should open the application screen. (code below)

I have listed two ways to do this below

**Problem:**

After clicking, it takes a few seconds for the application to open.

I would like the application in the memory bar to open after clicking

```
MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - clickStartTimer < FloatingWidgetView.CLICK_DELTA) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "clicked floating widget", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        val configIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        configIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        configIntent.data = Uri.parse(configIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))

        val pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            configIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        // Second method
        // val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        // startActivity(context, intent, null)
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "floating app widget"? are you using `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION`?

Answer (score 0):

try out my snippet, at first check link from comment (sorry for Java, its just copy-paste from working project). code is executed in `Service`, which is starting when all `Activites` are dropped to background (aka. "homed" case)

```
            Intent i = new Intent(this, mainActivityClass);
            // brings back whole activitys stack
            i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

            // http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4536
            boolean showToastBecauseOfDelay;
            try { // works without delay till Android P, on Q also delayed...
                pendingIntent.send();
                showToastBecauseOfDelay = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27;
            } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
                // startActivity may cause delay!!
                // when called less that 5 sec after Home button press...
                startActivity(i);
                showToastBecauseOfDelay = true;
            }

            // service starts when app/activity goes to background ("homed")
            // Toast will be shown only if user want to go back quickly after that
            // (just for some distration and feedback that click was registered)
            long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - serviceStartedAt;
            if (showToastBecauseOfDelay && diff < 5000) {
                // long - 3.5 sec, short 2 - sec, no other option
                int toastDuration = diff < 2000 ? Toast.LENGTH_LONG : Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.resuming_app, toastDuration).show();
            }
```